# Negative subscripts in matrix indexing

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

In Rcpp/RcppArmadillo I want to do the following: From an n x n matrix A, I would like to extract a submatrix A[-j, -j] where j is a vector of indices: In R it can go like

```
A = matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
j = c(2, 3)
A[-j, -j]
```

Seems that this functionality is not available in Rcpp or RcppArmadillo - sorry if I have overlooked something. One approach in R is

```
pos = setdiff(1:nrow(A), j)
A[pos, pos]
```

That will carry over to RcppArmadillo, but it seems akward having to create the vector pos as the complement of j - and I am not sure how to do it efficiently.

Does anyone have an idea for an efficient implementation / or a piece of code to share?

Comment: The overarching problem is that `A[-i, -j]` is an R expression, governed by the R interpreter.  Once you are in a line of code in `src/*` you are governed by the C (or C++, close enough) compiler where this means something else.  There is not a lot we can do.  You need a mediating layer and the provided answer is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The armadillo [docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) have the function [`.shed`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#shed) which takes an argument(s) that "... contains the indices of rows/columns/slices to remove". From my reading to remove both rows and columns will take two calls of `.shed()`.

Using your example

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat fun(arma::mat X, arma::uvec row, arma::uvec col) {
  X.shed_cols(col); // remove columns
  X.shed_rows(row); // remove rows
  return(X);
}


/***R
A = matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
j = c(2, 3)
A[-j, -j]

# minus one for zero indexing
fun(A, j-1, j-1)
*/
```

Comment: Nice, and probably as good as it gets for the issue at hand.